# Lighthouse Multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, audit, lighthouse

There's a website I need to do a full audit on, but I'm wondering if there's any way to make Lighthouse do it. I know they don't support full site audits or multiple URLs, but I found out that it could maybe be done with using bash scripts. So I would appreciate any help on this case! Or maybe any Lighthouse alternatives you'd recommend?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could make a shell or batch script to loop over the urls and make a call for each one... what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: Then check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file . You can use it to makea little script to loop over all your pages

Comment: The script file is done and working, but now I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to make it save the html file reports with full url as their names.

Comment: Well, this is matter of a new question

Comment: Yeah, I figured, so I started a new question, added my script and the urls i'm testing on.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and while looking for a good solution came across this nifty little package - ***[lighthouse-batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse-batch)***

All I had to do was run the following by passing URL's separated by a comma:

```
lighthouse-batch -s https://www.url1.com,https://www.url2.com,https://www.url3.com
```

You also get the summary of all the sites passed in a single `summary.json` file as well as a detailed report for each site by under the file `site_url.json`

Comment: How to make it work with authenticated websites?

Comment: Since Lighthouse-batch internally uses [lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/), you can see a few ways to authenticate [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/HEAD/docs/authenticated-pages.md)

Answer (score 2):

In my company, we wanted to collect website's performance data on most of the pages on our landing website, app product, and also our rivals' product, so sometimes there are hundreds of URLs that need to be audited.

I created a tool:

**[lighthouse-batch-parallel](https://github.com/Carr1005/lighthouse-batch-parallel)**

which could audit multiple URLs. You can get the report result in JS Object, JSON, CSV stream, or you can just use the provided cli-tool to generate the report in `.csv` or `.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to audit multiple URLs,as long as you loop over some array of urls programatically. I suggest first launching your chrome instance with chromeLauncher, then either launchings chrome for each url and writing results to some result directory in parallel, or do the same action but sequentially. When you have received the results from all of the urls, kill the chrome launcher and node process.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self promotion, but I wrote the [Multihouse](https://github.com/samdutton/multihouse) Node app to run Lighthouse for multiple URLs.

The app takes URLs and optional metadata from an input CSV file (one row per URL), runs one or more audits, and outputs median scores to an output CSV file.

You can specify multiple different options from the command line.

For example:

- The number of times Lighthouse is run for each URL. The default is three.
- Whether to calculate the average or median scores for all the runs. The default is median.
- Which Lighthouse audits to run. The default is all audits: Performance, Best practice, PWA, Accessibility, SEO.
- Whether to include results for all individual audits or for [Web Vitals](https://web.dev/vitals).

You might also want to take a look at [Related projects](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse#related-projects) on the Lighthouse GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it can be achieved using lhci, a tool to automate accessibility reports with Lighthouse and optionally store it in a dedicated server.

Lhci has the `collect` command that runs for multiple urls if provided.

```sh
lhci autorun --collect.url=http://example-1.com --collect.url=http://example-2.com
```

or creating a file lighthouserc.js

```js
{
  "ci": {
    // ...,
    "collect": {
      "url": ["http://example-1.com", "http://example-2.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from this Github issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/issues/124