# Run lighthouse for multiple pages/URLs

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

How can I run lighthouse for multiple pages/URLs without having to run the lighthouse-ci command multiple times for every single page I want to test/audit?

#### How I currently run my lighthouse tests for my pages.

- `lighthouse-ci --performance=80 --seo=80 --accessibility=80 --best-practices=80 <url-1>`
- `lighthouse-ci --performance=80 --seo=80 --accessibility=80 --best-practices=80 <url-2>`
- `lighthouse-ci --performance=80 --seo=80 --accessibility=80 --best-practices=80 <url-3>`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64024162/51593 for suggestions on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and while looking for a good solution came across this nifty little package - ***[lighthouse-batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse-batch)***

All I had to do was run the following by passing URL's separated by a comma:

```
lighthouse-batch -s https://www.url1.com,https://www.url2.com,https://www.url3.com
```

You also get the summary of all the sites passed in a single `summary.json` file as well as a detailed report for each site under the file `site_url.json`

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of luck with [Lighthouse Parade](https://github.com/cloudfour/lighthouse-parade), another CLI package. It runs a Lighthouse report on all pages discoverable from the url you provide:

```
npx lighthouse-parade http://www.dfwfreeways.com/
```

Pro tip: run it at night or give it a limit on the number of pages to run if you're not familiar with how many pages are on a domain :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of cli, you can write a program, where you can read urls from a file
you can use this for reference
https://github.com/gowthamraj198/Lighthouse

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. So I built a web tool for that: https://qualitycs.dev

It crawls sitemap to find new pages then it runs lighthouse regularly.
Issues are listed per page and globally. Meaning that you can directly see site wise issues such as cache, dans, https etc.

I'm actively working on it so new features are coming.

Answer (score 0):

...chiming in late here, but you're now able to provide a list of urls in your .lighthouserc configs:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#url

Example:

```
module.exports = {
  ci: {
    collect: {
      url: [
       'https://www.nytimes.com',
       'https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2023/03/12/sports/natural-selection-snowboarding-travis-rice.html'
      ],
     // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell you could call an invoke-webrequest for each endpoint if you are building a solution in Nodejs/ExpressJs> Just make sure the invoke-webrequests are sequentially executed.